# Why do I get "FATAL: parse 'gl-conf' failed: Permission denied" when installing GitLab 4.0?

Tags: gitolite, gitlab

I'm trying to install a brand new instance of GitLab 4.0 onto an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I follow the guide at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md all the way up to the end of step 4.

When I try to clone the gitolite-admin repository, it fails like this:

```
root@ws-prod-git-01:/home/git# sudo -u gitlab -H git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin.git /tmp/gitolite-admin
Cloning into '/tmp/gitolite-admin'...
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
FATAL: parse 'gl-conf' failed: Permission denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried just ssh'ing in with the git user, but this is what I got:

```
root@ws-prod-git-01:/home/git# ssh -i /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa git@localhost
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello gitlab, this is git@ws-prod-git-01 running gitolite3 v3.2-gitlab-patched-0-g2d29cf7 on git 1.7.9.5

FATAL: parse 'gl-conf' failed: Permission denied
Connection to localhost closed.
```

This is the second time running through the set up process. I got the same errors the first time, so reset and tried again.

The permission denied error makes me think my permissions are set wrong, but I copied and pasted exactly what the installation guide told me to:

```
# Make sure the repositories dir is owned by git and it stays that way
sudo chmod -R ug+rwXs,o-rwx /home/git/repositories/
sudo chown -R git:git /home/git/repositories/
```

So, what should I try now?

Edit:

For various reasons, I mount my /home from an NFS share. On the off chance something was going on with that, I made a VM that didn't mount from NFS at all. Using that, I did NOT get the gl-conf error.

I then recreated the VM with the NFS shares, and the error reappeared.

Note that I have an old Gitlab v2.something install running that works with the NFS shares just fine.

Any thoughts on how NFS would effect this?

Comment: Do you have set `UMASK` to `007` in your `.gitolite.rc` as I do in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L27 ? And what is the value of `umask` on your gitolite server?

Comment: I did nothing except what the guide said to do. I'll go check the .gitolite.rc file though.

Comment: Looks like UMASK is already 0007

Comment: "Note that I have an old Gitlab v2". Yet you mention a GitLab 4 at the beginning of your question. If you are talking about Gitolite, your ssh also display gitolite3.

Comment: Gitlab has their own fork of gitolite. That's the gitolite version I'm installing. `sudo -u git -H git clone -b gl-v320 https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitolite.git /home/git/gitolite` is the line the install guide gives me. Looks like gitolive v320? My Gitlab v2 instance is so old that I was having lots of problems upgrading. Which is why I wanted to start from scratch.

Comment: Starting from scratch would mean cloning the latest from gitolite 3 (as I do in my script)

Comment: Starting from scratch means creating a clean server, then following GitLab's install instructions exactly. Which means cloning their fork of gitolite. I have no idea what the differences between the forks would be, or how to see if they are why NFS seems to cause problems.

Comment: I do see their gitolite (in gitlabhd) now. Never used it though. I like to clone the latest and configure it directly.